# how to group input fields in a webpage(not in a common form), based on its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I  have a web page. and it contains top left a search button and in the middle of the page a group of input fields. unfortunately there is no form i need to wrap a form dynamically in to these. first group should be in the first form and second group in another form like that.

need to group it based on its position.

Comment: i tried this logic http://jsfiddle.net/v4gr1ykg/4/ (got from one  post from here )

Comment: Please would you add some code you already have and describe what should happen / when it should happen?

Comment: i ended up with solution in kmeans algorithm implemteation..